# What is the name of the device that combines and synchronizes two AC sources into one?

Tags: ac, dc, rectifier

I saw this device on Amazon for $450, I already forgot what it was called and am trying to find it again.

It let you combine two AC sources, and the voltage would only flow one way, and it would create one AC output with the two sources synchronized.

Comment: It is unlikely that this device could force two AC sources to synchronise. I'd say there's something else going on.

Comment: "Voltage" doesn't flow, (power or current does, "AC" implies the current flows in both directions), and you can't force an arbitrary external power source to be synchronous to a different source. Something gets mixed up here. What is the *purpose* of the device?

Comment: Sounds not unlike a grid tie inverter but perhaps not for use on an actual utility grid.   There's no simple way to combine independant AC sources, you basically have to pull the energy out of one (recifier and capacitor bank) and resynthesize it in synch with the other.

Comment: @ChrisStratton for $450, maybe it's doing that

Comment: @sergiy - please provide the amazon link

Comment: To be meaningful, your question really needs details of the application.  What are you trying to accomplish?  What are the sources, what are the load(s) and what power levels / currents are involved?  Some random thing you saw on an ecommerce site might be applicable, but much more likely would not be.

Answer (score 1):

There are two tasks similar to your request.

- Connect an AC-generator to an AC-grid.
- Uninterruptible power supply.

To connect the AC-generator to the AC-grid (and prevent the AC-generator from becoming a load) you must:

1. Set the amplitude from generator equal to amplitude from the grid
2. Set the same frequency
3. Set the same phase

These functions are commonly integrated in the generator controller.

To make uninterruptible power supply an AC-DC-AC chain is built. This chain as well as frequency and phase tracking is also included in the UPS controller.

P.S. There are some similar systems like [HVDC Cross-Channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HVDC_Cross-Channel) but there cost is much more than 450$

If we are talking about [rampage of green energetics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320951285_Operation_strategy_for_grid-tied_DC-coupling_power_converter_interface_integrating_windsolarbattery/fulltext/5a045547aca272b06caa130d/Operation-strategy-for-grid-tied-DC-coupling-power-converter-interface-integrating-wind-solar-battery.pdf) with local solar panels, wind generators, litium batterys and connection to the common AC-grid then you may look at something like [Kinergier Pro](https://www.pure-sineinverter.com/sale-12304193-4kw-6kw-8kw-solar-inverter-charger-ac-coupling-dc-coupling-system.html) ([350$](https://tbbpower.en.made-in-china.com/product/MXbQZwGVHnfm/China-AC-Coupled-Inverter-Charger-off-Grid-Generator-Multiplus.html)).